# Formatting biblatex phdthesis for APA7

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, thesis, apa7

I'm trying to format a `@phdthesis` according to APA style style. Here is my bib file (`apa-test.bib`):

```
@phdthesis{example,
  author = {Hollander, M. M.},
  year = {2017},
  title = {Resistance to authority: Methodological innovations and new lessons from the {Milgram} experiment},
  number = {10289373},
  school = {University of Wisconsin-Madison},
  publisher = {{ProQuest Dissertations and Theses Global}}
}
```

And a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sortcites}

\begin{document}
Here is an example dissertation from \textcite{example}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This currently renders as:

> Hollander,  M. M. (2017). *Resistance to authority: Methodological innovations and new lessons from the Milgram experiment* (PhD thesis Nos. 10289373). University of Wisconsin-Madison; ProQuest Dissertations and Theses Global.

However, APA version 7 requires this formatting:

> Hollander,  M. M. (2017). *Resistance to authority: Methodological innovations and new lessons from the Milgram experiment* (Publication No. 10289373) [Doctoral dissertation, University of Wisconsin-Madison]. ProQuest Dissertations and Theses Global.

I've can make the "Publication No." appear correctly by setting `type = {Publication}` in my `.bib` file. However, I have been unable to make "Doctoral dissertation" appear with the school, or make that appear in brackets. I've tried, for example:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{school}{%
  \brackettext{Doctoral dissertation, #1}}
```

But have not had any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `biblatex-apa` does not produce the correct output according to the 7th edition of the APA manual, please report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues (even if you find a work-around in the meantime).

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/112